# delphi canvas drawtext does not clip the text

Tags: delphi, canvas, drawtext, synpdf

I am using Windows 10, Delphi 7. Trying to make Pdf document with SynPDF using it's canvas directly. I need to draw in the rectangle only that part of the text that corresponds to the length of the rectangle, the rest cut off. I am using DrawText (and DrawTextEx) functions to write text in the given rectangle with alignment (TA_LEFT, TA_RIGHT, TA_CENTER).
  The problem: these functions draw the text, but do not take into account the given boundaries - they do not clip(crop) this text.

```
var 
  R: TRect;
  s: String;
begin
    R:= Rect(50, 50, 120, 75);
    Canvas.Brush.Color:=clYellow;
    Canvas.Rectangle(R);  
    Canvas.Font.Name:='Arial';
    Canvas.Font.Size:=10;
    Canvas.Font.Style:=[];
    Canvas.Brush.Style:= bsClear;
    s:='Sample for text clipping';        
    DrawText(Canvas.Handle, PChar(s), -1, R, TA_LEFT or 
            {DT_END_ELLIPSIS or }DT_VCENTER or DT_SINGLELINE);
end;
```

If I add `DT_END_ELLIPSIS` it works correctly but adds three dots - I do not need dots. What I am doing wrong? Or I need to use other functions for my task?

Unfortunately, I'm not allowed (by StackOverflow) to add a photo with the result...

Comment: You can use [Canvas.TextRect](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Graphics.TCanvas.TextRect).

Comment: Can you check if this works with a standard Windows canvas on screen? It might be a feature of SynPDF, as the Windows Docs state that DrawText actually does clipping unless DT_NOCLIP is given.

Comment: @whosrdaddy I tried Canvas.TextRect it works! Although it is less convenient than DrawText. Than you!

Comment: @UweRaabe  I checked if DrawText works on Windows Canvas - and it works perfectly (so and TextRect). Now I am sure where to dig! I even can not tell why I did not try it before... Most likely the problem is in SynPDF.

Comment: There is a Version of SynPdf that should work.
Look at:
https://synopse.info/forum/viewtopic.php?pid=27877#p27877

Comment: @Fritzw Thanks! It works! But I'm not sure if I downloaded the right version. I downloaded SynPDF.pas, which is at the very beginning of the post, the link to which you gave me.

Comment: Yes these is the version